# IDEA: Custom Ant step right before upload to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I am developing a Google App Engine application using IntelliJ IDEA.

I need to do some pre-processing right before the artefacts get uploaded to app engine. Is it possible to configure somehow an Ant build step right before the GAE upload begins?

Help much appreciated.

Regards,
Roshan

Comment: How does the upload get launched? Is it via a GAE plugin, or something else like maven?

Comment: It is through "Google App Engine" IDEA plugin, which adds the following menu option - "Tools -> Upload App Engine Application". However, I am unable to find if there is any way I can customize what this "upload" step does - hook-up any pre- / post- processing tasks.